# Add func in onDelete's perform in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The code is as following:

```
Section(header: Text("Head")) {
    ForEach() { child in
        ...
    }
    .onDelete(perform: self.db.delete)  <-- how to add other func in perform???
}
```

And I want to add some other func when `onDelete` occurs like:

```
    .onDelete(perform: self.db.delete,
        otherFunc()
    )

func otherFunc() {
}
```

The `self.db.delete` after `perform` is not easy to move to `otherFunc()` and I want to keep it not changing.

Then how to make it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you create a function for these actions? I mean create a function that calls `otherFunction` and `self.db.delete` then you can declare like `.onDelete(perform: self.myFunction)`. In `myFunction` you should call `self.db.delete()` and `otherFunction()`

Comment: Thanks, @emrcftci. I know this method. But the `self.db.delete()` is not easy to add in `self.myFunction`. Is there any other ways to keep the `self.db.delete()` not moving and add another func `otherFuncion()` in `onDelete`?

Comment: What's so special about `self.db.delete()` that you can't move it to another place in the same class/struct? If you forward parameters from `onDelete(perform:)` it should have the same effect as calling directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another function and pass to it the same parameters from `onDelete(perform:)`:

```
Section(header: Text("Head")) {
    ForEach() { child in
        ...
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
```

And inside call `self.db.delete` with the same parameters as originally.

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    self.db.delete(offsets)
    otherFunction()
}
```